# How to convert bitmap data into image file in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip, bitmapdata

I want to convert bitmap data to an image file like jpg or png file in AS3 
can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as3corelib (available at http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) comes with JPGEncoder and PNGEncoder classes!

Comment: alternatively you can use Alchemy with libpng or libjpeg for faster speeds, but unless this is time critical stuff as3corelib should be more than enough.

Comment: Thanks @Lowgain for your help 
it works nice now with as3corelib :)